# The area of Maclaurin trisectrix

Tags: calculus, area

I was attempting to calculate the area bounded by Maclaurin trisectrix
$$
x(t)=\frac{a\sin 3t}{\sin t},\quad y(t)=\frac{a\sin 3t}{\cos t},
$$ 
but I've encountered a problem, while figuring out the boundaries of integration. The thing is that I can't find the second point where y(t) = 0, because it turns into (0,0). I would really appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: When $t\to 0$ you get $y(0)=0$ and $x(0)=3a$.

Comment: And when $t\to \frac \pi 3$, $x=y=0$. So, the area of half the loop is given by the integral from $0$ to  $ \frac \pi 3$. By the way, did you solve the integral ?

Comment: Yes, i did. I used previous advice to find the limit and get that 3a.